# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discusión, site-evaluation

We all love [Spanish Language Stack Exchange](http://spanish.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Verbs ending in "-ed"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12039/verbs-ending-in-ed)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [The difference between the use of "es" and "está"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12092/the-difference-between-the-use-of-es-and-est%c3%a1)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the difference between «pensar en» and just «pensar»?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12120/what-is-the-difference-between-pensar-en-and-just-pensar)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Confused over "vacilar"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/11969/confused-over-vacilar)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Question on possesives](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/11999/question-on-possesives)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to translate engagement](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12023/how-to-translate-engagement)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [meanings of "estar a la que salta"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/11932/meanings-of-estar-a-la-que-salta)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Pretéritos fuertes desusados](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12137/pret%c3%a9ritos-fuertes-desusados)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Where else 'Se' in comerse will be used](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/11947/where-else-se-in-comerse-will-be-used)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What would be the equivalent to "feature completeness" in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12042/what-would-be-the-equivalent-to-feature-completeness-in-spanish)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---